# Test Next Element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

How do I test if the next element is certain type - e.g. I want to test if the next element following an image, is also an image. If so, then I want to add a class to that element

e.g. if this was the case then it would trigger true and add a class to the first image...

```
<p></p>
<img />
<img />
<p></p>
```

However, in this case then it would trigger false, and nothing would happen...

```
<p></p>
<img />
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method of jQuery to do that:

```
$("#yourimage").next().is("img");
```

So to add a class like you describe:

```
var yourimage = $("#yourimage");

if (yourimage.next().is("img")){
   yourimage.addClass("yourExtraClass");
}
```

Comment: +1, seems like the only answer that actually does what the question suggests is required.

Comment: Gave Felix a +1 (especially liked the img + img technique), but liked this answer better (not sure why exactly, sorry to be subjective!). Incidentally the target was not unique so I iterated through each like so...

`$('img').each(function(){
 if($(this).next().is('img')) {
  $(this).addClass('test');
 };
});`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`.next()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/next/) together with [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('img').filter(function() {
    return $(this).next('img').length === 1;
}).addClass('someClass');
```

You can also use the [*next adjacent selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) with [`.prev()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prev/):

```
$('img + img').prev().addClass('someClass');
```

Comment: @Anthony: No it does not. `.next` selects the following sibling **if and only if** it matches the selector. Have a look at the documentation.

Comment: Yep, you're right - just went and checked the docs. Brief moment of confusion on my part. With that cleared up, seems like two very good solutions to the problem. +1!

Comment: Two nice solutions, prettier than mine! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
var nextImage = $(this).next('img');
```

The `next` method accepts the standard jQuery selectors.